# Binding key to save in specific directory?

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings

I want to bind a key to save a timestamped backup of the current buffer to a specific directory. For example `C-§` will save my current buffer to `~/Org/Backups/2017-01-01-foo.org`.

Unfortunately every answer for something similar that I've seen looks unnecessary complicated and I would like to keep a simple binding for what should be a simple task.

Comment: Another option might be to allow Emacs to make backups automatically and set `make-backup-file-name-function` to control how backup files are named.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my take on a command doing what you want, and also how to bind it to the desired key.

```
(defun save-timestamped-backup ()
  "Save a timestamped backup of current buffer to ~/Org/Backups"
  (interactive)
  (write-region (point-min) (point-max)
                (format "~/Org/Backups/%s-%s"
                        (format-time-string "%Y-%m-%d")
                        (buffer-name))))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-§") #'save-timestamped-backup)
```